# How to plot points with uncertainties and dates assigned?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a graph from list of points, but each point also has uncertainty assigned AND date.
Without uncertainties DateListPlot works great, without dates ErrorListPlot works OK, but how it could be done both at the same time?

I tried displaying 2 plots (DateListPlot + ErrorListPlot) using Show, but it didn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plots can't be directly combined because the `PlotRange` of the `DateListPlot` is far out to the right on the horizontal axis, since it corresponds to a large `AbsoluteTime` value. So we have to convert the `ErrorListPlot` to the same coordinate range before combining the plots using `Show`:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]


data = {{{2006, 10, 1}, 10, 1}, {{2006, 10, 15}, 
    12, .1}, {{2006, 10, 30}, 15, 2}, {{2006, 11, 20}, 20, 1}};

data2 = 
 Map[{{AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]], #[[2]]}, ErrorBar[#[[3]]]} &, data]

(*
==> {{{3368649600, 10}, ErrorBar[1]}, {{3369859200, 12}, 
  ErrorBar[0.1]}, {{3371155200, 15}, ErrorBar[2]}, {{3372969600, 20}, 
  ErrorBar[1]}}
*)

errorp = ErrorListPlot[data2];

datep = DateListPlot[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]];

Show[datep, errorp]
```

[image: combined]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly.^^